# Cannot get thumbnail in rss feed in laravel

Tags: laravel, rss, rss-reader, feedparser, simplepie

I am using willvincent feed reader to parse rss feeds, But i cannot seem to get the thumbail of the images,
Here is my code

```
Route::get('feed', function(Request $request) {
    $f = FeedsFacade::make('http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/us/feed/');

    // $results = [
    //     'image' => $f->get_image_url(),
    // ];
    
    foreach($f->get_items(0, $f->get_item_quantity()) as $item) {
        $i['title'] = $item->get_title();
        $i['thumbnail'] = $item->get_thumbnail();
        $i['description'] = $item->get_description();
        $i['content'] = $item->get_content();
        $i['link'] = $item->get_link();
        $i['date'] = $item->get_date();

        $results['items'][] = $i;
    }

    dd($results);

})->name('feed');
```

Thumbnail always return null, will appreciate anyone's help

Comment: Are you sure `->get_thumbnail()` exists? `<thumbnail>` as well as `<isVideoArticle>` in that feed are not standard RSS2.0. Any link to a SimplePie method `->get_thumbnail()`?

Comment: I checked the documentation and there is no <thumbnail> tag or <isVideoArticle> tag in rss 2.0.  But most of the sites have thumbnail tag in their rss feed. So now how am i supposed to get the thumbnail image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we call image and other contents from rss feed

**NOTE:** To get image, it is important that the site you fetching rss feeds, use to provide image too in their feed. Else won't get image in your fetched feed *(there might be some trick to still fetch image but I am not aware of it for now)*. For example, google news feed don't provide image so you won't get image from google news feed.

Here is example of one site who use to provide image.

```
//In your CONTROLLER file

 $feed = Feeds::make('https://globalnews.ca/feed/');
    $data = array(
      'title'     => $feed->get_title(),
      'permalink' => $feed->get_permalink(),
      'items'     => $feed->get_items(),
    );
  
 return view('view_file', $data)

//OR in case you are calling array value to show on view then it would be like this

return view('view_file', array(
   'name' =>  $var 
 ), $data)   //notice "$data" at end of array.
```

Now after done on controller part, this is how you will call in view file

```
@foreach ($items as $item)

    //GET IMAGE
    @if($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
        <img src="{{$enclosure->get_thumbnail()}}">
    @endif

    //GET TITLE
    <div class="news-title">{{ $item->get_title() }}</div>

    //GET DESCRIPTION
    {{$item->get_description()}}

    //NOTE: this will bring html. TO show as output instead of html you can either use {!!  !!) or "strip_tags" function. And "substr" function to show first 100 characters only as small description
    {{ substr(strip_tags($item->get_description()), 0, 100) }}

   //GET LINK/URL OF NEWS
   <a href="{{ $item->get_permalink() }}" target="_blank">Read More</a>

@endforeach
```

Feed which whose example I shown and also reference

https://packagist.org/packages/willvincent/feeds

Comment: Yes i figured it out, But thanks for telling, I will marks this as the correct answer